# How to create a simple WebSocket Server in Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to develop a Chrome App that will work together with a Chrome Extension that I already created, wherein the Chrome Extension will send information to the Chrome App.

For this communication I thought use the WebSocket locally, in Chrome Extension I managed to make the Client, but now I'm having difficulty in creating the Server in the Chrome App, because I wanted to make as simple as possible without having to install something beyond of the Chrome App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the first Google results there is a sample app from Chrome team: [Http WebSocket Server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/websocket-server).

You've got to understand that making a server in Chrome Apps is difficult; you are given access to a raw socket, and you need to fully implement the protocol that a particular server must use. Even a HTTP server is non-trivial, WebSockets is even less so.

So: it's possible, but it's not simple unless you're using an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the accepted answer:

There is a Chrome Extension already in the Chrome Web Store: [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb).

And it is opensource: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome). You can use it as a library to your Chrome App.

Cheers!